# "date not valid for month specified" error

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am running the below query but i keep getting the error "date not valid for month specified"

```
update PERSONNEL P 
set P.ACTIVE =UPPER('N') 
where 
    P.PERSONNEL_ID in (SELECT PERSONNEL_ID 
                        FROM 
                        (select 
                            a.personnel_id, a.expiry_date, p.active
                            , nvl(count(t.personnel_id),0)total 
                        from  PERSONNEL P, 
                        (select * from   (
                            select 
                                a.*
                                ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PERSONNEL_ID order by "EXPIRY_DATE" desc) as AN 
                            from   ATTENDANCE a 
                            where a. COURSE in (select COURSE 
                                                from COURSES
                                                where DESCRIPTION like '%OFFSHORE SAFETY PERMIT%' 
                                                and description like '%INFREQUENT%' ))
where  
    AN = 1 
    and  trunc(expiry_date) >= trunc(sysdate))a 
    left join trip_history t 
    on a.personnel_id =t.personnel_id 
    where p.personnel_id =a.personnel_id  
    and trunc(a.expiry_date) >= trunc(sysdate) 
    and p.active ='Y' 
    and TRUNC(T.CHANGED) between 
    (SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR ((A.DATE_ATTENDED+1),'fmDD')||'-'||TO_CHAR ((A.DATE_ATTENDED+1), 'fmmonth')||'-'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY')) 
    FROM DUAL)
    and( (a.DATE_ATTENDED-1) + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'year')) 
    group by a.personnel_id, a.expiry_date, p.active 
    HAVING COUNT(T.PERSONNEL_ID)>='4'));
```

It's part of a procedure that was working before now, I have an idea it's as a result of the leap year, but i have no idea what else to do.

Comment: so without tables and data it is quite hatd to debug, so do it yourself

Comment: Run each of the subqueries on their own until you find the one causing the error and then debug that single query

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
and( (a.DATE_ATTENDED-1) + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'year'))
```

The documentation for [interval arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) states:

> When interval calculations return a datetime value, the result must be an actual datetime value or the database returns an error.

If the `DATE_ATTENDED` is `2024-03-01` then:

- `(a.DATE_ATTENDED-1)` is `2024-02-29` and:
- `(a.DATE_ATTENDED-1) + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'year')` is `2025-02-29` which does not exist.

Don't add an `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` unless you know that the day-of-month with **ALWAYS** be valid.

If it is not always going to be valid then use the `ADD_MONTHS` function:

```sql
and ADD_MONTHS((a.DATE_ATTENDED-1), 12)
```